# MySQL: How to implement history of product price and units

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I am using MySQL to store product information where the price and number of units may change so I need to implement history somehow. Thinking about it I have created a table product: ID, name and table product_state: ID, price, units, product_id. I identify the latest product_state by the highest ID.

How to create a database query allowing me to get every product in its current state?

I am able to get it for a single product using this query:

```
SELECT * FROM product, product_state
WHERE product.id=%i AND product_state.product_id=product.id
ORDER BY product_state.id DESC LIMIT 1;
```

But I need to get a set of all product in its current state and I dont know how to make the query:

```
SELECT * FROM product, product_state
WHERE product.id = product_state.product_id
ORDER BY product_state.id DESC;
```

This will also return me the old product states which I don't want right now.

Is it possible to create such query or is there some better way to implement the history?

For example:

product(id,name): 1, dog
product_state(id,price,units,product_id): 1, 100,23, 1
product_state(id,price,units,product_id): 2, 134, 12, 1

result after query should be: 1, dog, 2, 134, 12, 1

Comment: can you give sample records where we can test it? and also your desired result.

Comment: How do you identify the newest product state?

Comment: Stop using implicit `JOIN` syntax.

Comment: added answers to the questions as edit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM product
  JOIN product_state ps on product.id = ps.product_id
WHERE ps.id = (select max(ps2.id) 
                 from product_state ps2 
                where ps2.product_id = ps.product_id) 
ORDER BY ps.id DESC;
```

Comment: this will also give the old product states together with the new ones, so the result is the same as with my query. Products with no product states does not matter to me.

Comment: Did you try it? But I ask again, how do you identify a new product state? Above will give only the product states with the highest id, so if it is by id it will not show you the old ones.

Comment: yes I did try it, you have there an error: in the order by should be ps instead of product_state. I fixed it to work: you need to replace the id in where in the subquery by product_id:
SELECT * FROM product
LEFT OUTER JOIN product_state ps on product.id = ps.product_id
WHERE ps.id is null 
  or  ps.id = (select max(ps2.id) from product_state ps2 
                            where ps2.product_id = ps.product_id) 
ORDER BY ps.id DESC;

Comment: @hol . . . You need to change your correlated `where` clause to `where ps2.product_id = ps.product_id`.  Otherwise, the subquery is a no-op.

Comment: @hol max(ps2.id) was right, the product_id belongs only to where in the subquery

Comment: @Ragnar wow, heavy team work here. Thanks. Should work now, shouldn't it?